# Navigation Bar Item stretching image for button

Tags: ios, ios5, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I have setup a Navigation Bar in a storyboard with an UIBarButton for the right.

[image]

This is the code I use to update the image for this:

```
// Setup the right navigation bar item
[self.addGameButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"addGameButton"] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[self.addGameButton setTitle:@""];
```

The image is here, it is 76x58 (at 2x). It is 38x29 (at normal).
[image]

When run on the device the image is stretching and I do not know why?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The backgroundImage property is meant to draw a stretchable image for the background of the button. If you want the image inside the button, you could try initializing the UIBarButtonItem with this:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"images/global/add"];
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:image style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:barButtonItem];
```

For you, it looks like you have an image that you want to replace the whole button with. You could also try this code, which will create a custom button as the view for your UIBarButtonItem:

```
UIImage *addImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"images/global/add"];
UIButton *addButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[addButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, addImage.size.width, addImage.size.height)];
[addButton setBackgroundImage:addImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:addButton];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:barButtonItem];
```

Comment: Thanks thats it. I have a follow on question, should a different image be used for the navigation bar item when in portrait at a smaller height etc?

Answer (score 1):

In storyboard you can dragg a UIButton over the UIBarButtonItem and you can customise the UIButton as you like.

Comment: How did you set the image to the UIButton ? You should use `- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state` and I tried this part and it's working.

Comment: Also, if you don't whant a custom image on the button and you just whant a __+__ image then you can use UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd for the UIBarButtonItem.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the frame of the button to the size you want.

Comment: Frame is not a property on UIBarButtonItem and I cannot initWithFrame either. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Stuart, since you have setTitle:@"" the nav bar button will not display the text "add" but instead take up the space that was allocated to the text.. I am also yet to find a proper solution but a workaround for your problem is to set the font size to 0.1f. This will resolve your issue..

you need to set the navigation bar appearance in the "application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions” method of AppDelegate.m, try adding the following code:

```
UIImage *buttonback = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_back"]
resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 22, 0, 0)];

    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance]
setBackButtonBackgroundImage:buttonback forState:UIControlStateNormal
barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary
dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor whiteColor],
UITextAttributeTextColor, [UIFont fontWithName:@"verdana" size:0.1f],
UITextAttributeFont, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Also Note that this will work with iOS 6, looking for a solution for compatibility in iOS 5

Comment: Thanks, how do I access the font for the bar button item?